# Delete row based on partial text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete the entire row if I find the text 'FemImplant' in column A.

The text is part of a sentence linked by '$'. I need to parse the cell content before '$' and see if it matches 'FemImplant' and delete that row.

This is what I have so far.

```
Dim cell As Excel.Range
RowCount = DataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set col = DataSheet.Range("A1:A" & RowCount)
Dim SheetName As String
Dim ParsedCell() As String

For Each cell In col
    ParsedCell = cell.Value.Split("$")
    SheetName = ParsedCell(0)

    If SheetName = "FemImplant" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next
```

Comment: The main problem I am having is that, i am not able to make it loop from the bottom. The way i have it set up is looping from the top and it is not deleting consecutive rows.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use AutoFilter to delete the rows which contain the text `FemImplant$`. This method will be much faster than looping.

If you are working with **Boolean** values then you may want to see [Trying to Delete Rows with False Value in my Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64112769/trying-to-delete-rows-with-false-value-in-my-range)

See this example

I am assuming that Cell A1 has header.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    strSearch = "FemImplant$"
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        '~~> Filter, offset(to exclude headers) and delete visible rows
        With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
          .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
          .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]