# Deleting rows if #N/A or selecting only rows that aren't #N/A

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am building a macro in VBA to do a number of different functions, one of them will be copying data into the report from a different spreadsheet. The master spreadsheet that will be giving the data has data on all clients, I am using a VLOOKUP and then importing all the data that is relevant to that client. Is there a way to either:

1) look down a column for the first item that is `#N/A` and selecting all data above it (pulling the row number of the first `#N/A` would be useful and make the second bit easy

2) delete the row is column `U` is #N/A - the problem I've found with this is that the loop is very big and takes a long time, I used similar to the below link

[I want to delete the row if columns C,D and E has #N/A using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358834/i-want-to-delete-the-row-if-columns-c-d-and-e-has-n-a-using-vba)

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s) will get you started.

Comment: You can't filter by does not equal `#N/A` in VBA?

Comment: When in doubt, record a macro ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this fast enough??:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim N As Long, rFilter As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Set rFilter = Range("U1:U" & N)
        Set rr = Range("U2:U" & N)
        rFilter.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="#N/A"
        Set rkill = rr.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rkill.EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    rFilter(1).AutoFilter
End Sub
```