# Delete Rows Of Which Either Cells In Column A or B is Empty

Tags: excel, vba

Am having a slight malfunction with this line of codes. I intend for this code to loop and delete rows of which either cells in column A or cells in column B is empty.. This rows contains Clients Names in Column A and The Clients Number in Column B. Now when i execute the script, the first row deletes fine, but from the next row which ought to delete, the phone number begins to mix up.

Please, i just need the argument to be written in such a way it fetches all row which are true according to the conditions and delete, or any logic which might work, without mixing up datas Thank You.

NOTE: I would appreciate if correction or upgrade is done using my code below. Thank you

```
Dim rngRange As Range
    Dim rngUnion As Range
    Dim rngCEll As Range
    Set rngRange = Sheet2.UsedRange.Offset(7)
    For Each rngCEll In rngRange.Columns(1).Cells
        If rngCEll.Value = "" Or rngCEll.Offset(, 1).Value = "" Then
            If rngUnion Is Nothing Then
                Set rngUnion = rngCEll
            Else
                Set rngUnion = Union(rngUnion, rngCEll)
            End If
            End If
    Next rngCEll
    If Not rngUnion Is Nothing Then
        rngUnion.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
```

Comment: No need to loop. Use autofilter. I have answered many similar questions in the past. Please do a search

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-condition) is one such link

Comment: Ok, thank you.. let me try it out

Comment: If you use a loop and you delete rows/cols, always work backwards

Comment: Ok.. i tried using your sample from the link you provided, to filter 2 columns that starts from A7 and B7 respectively downward.. I got an error that says "The command could not be completed by using the range specified. select a single cell within the range and try again".

Comment: Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim lRow As Long

    strSearch = ""

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A7" & .Rows.Count, "B7" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        
        With .Range("A7:A" & lRow)
          .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
          .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

Comment: You could [edit] that code into your question, it would be so much prettier than in the comments section!