# VBA - Remove certain rows where after certain columns are empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel table looks like below:

```
Name  task date1  date2 date3  date4
John  t1    d1
Lucy  t2    
Mary  t3    d2    d3
```

I want to remove the rows whose columns after 3rd column (i.e. from `date1`) are empty (e.g. Lucy in this example)

I found the below example, I think it is close but not sure how I can modify it by choosing the empty rows after 3rd column instead of the whole row.

```
Sub DeleteAllEmptyRows()
    Dim LastRowIndex As Integer
    Dim RowIndex As Integer
    Dim UsedRng As Range

    Set UsedRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    LastRowIndex = UsedRng.Row - 1 + UsedRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For RowIndex = LastRowIndex To 1 Step -1
        If Application.CountA(Rows(RowIndex)) = 0 Then 'Some logic to add here to choose range
            Rows(RowIndex).Delete
        End If
    Next RowIndex

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any suggestions please? Thanks.

Comment: No need to loop. Filter for blanks on the 3rd column and delete. [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-condition) will get you started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is to first calculate the last column in the used range and then use it in the CountA statement inside the loop.

To calculate the last column, you could add the following lines right before the loop:

```
Dim LastColIndex As Integer: LastColIndex = UsedRng.Column - 1 + UsedRng.Columns.Count
```

The `If` statement would then need to look like something like this:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(RowIndex, 3), Cells(RowIndex, LastColIndex))) = 0 Then
```

This checks for non-empty values starting from the 3rd column in the current row.

The combined code would then look like this:

```
Sub DeleteAllEmptyRows()
    Dim LastRowIndex As Integer
    Dim RowIndex As Integer
    Dim UsedRng As Range

    Set UsedRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    LastRowIndex = UsedRng.Row - 1 + UsedRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim LastColIndex As Integer: LastColIndex = UsedRng.Column - 1 + UsedRng.Columns.Count

    For RowIndex = LastRowIndex To 1 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(RowIndex, 3), Cells(RowIndex, LastColIndex))) = 0 Then
            Rows(RowIndex).Delete
        End If
    Next RowIndex

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I would also change the `For` loop to count down to 2 instead of 1 to avoid the possibility of ever deleting the header row, but I guess that depends on your taste :)

---

**In case of phantom values ...**

Sometimes, cells have values that are invisible to the naked eye but are counted by Excel's `COUNTA` function, as when a cell has one or more spaces as its value. If those cases need to be accounted for, we can check each cell individually using the following VBA function:

```
Function IsBlankRange(ByRef rng As Range) As Boolean
    'For faster processing, read in the entire range into a memory variable
    '  instead of reading in each cell value from Excel
    Dim arr As Variant: arr = rng.Value

    'If the range contains a single value, check it and exit
    If Not IsArray(arr) Then 'With single-value ranges, arr will not be an array
        IsBlankRange = Trim(arr & "") = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    'If we are here, the range contains an array of values,
    '  so we must loop through the array

    'Assume the range is not blank
    IsBlankRange = False

    Dim arrLb1 As Long: arrLb1 = LBound(arr, 1)
    Dim arrUb1 As Long: arrUb1 = UBound(arr, 1)
    Dim arrLb2 As Long: arrLb2 = LBound(arr, 2)
    Dim arrUb2 As Long: arrUb2 = UBound(arr, 2)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = arrLb1 To arrUb1
        For j = arrLb2 To arrUb2
            'Return false (the value assumed above) on the first non-blank value
            If Trim(arr(i, j) & "") <> "" Then Exit Function
        Next
    Next

    'If we are here, no non-blank value was encountered, so the range is blank
    IsBlankRange = True
End Function
```

This function can be used to change the `If WorksheetFunction.CountA(...) = 0` line to

```
        If IsBlankRange(Range(Cells(RowIndex, 3), Cells(RowIndex, LastColIndex))) Then
```

In short, the new procedure would look like this:

```
Sub DeleteAllEmptyRows()
    Dim LastRowIndex As Integer
    Dim RowIndex As Integer
    Dim UsedRng As Range

    Set UsedRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    LastRowIndex = UsedRng.Row - 1 + UsedRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim LastColIndex As Integer: LastColIndex = UsedRng.Column - 1 + UsedRng.Columns.Count

    For RowIndex = LastRowIndex To 1 Step -1
        If IsBlankRange(Range(Cells(RowIndex, 3), Cells(RowIndex, LastColIndex))) Then
            Rows(RowIndex).Delete
        End If
    Next RowIndex

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Naturally, the new `IsBlankRange` function would need to be added as well (below the `DeleteAllEmptyRows` code, probably). The function can be made private to the module if it will never be used anywhere else.

---

**But, if you can use CONCAT ...**

The `IsBlankRange` function can be simplified if you have Excel 2019 and can use the new `CONCAT` function, which can be applied to a range:

```
Function IsBlankRange(ByRef rng As Range) As Boolean
    IsBlankRange = Trim(WorksheetFunction.Concat(rng) & "") = ""
End Function
```

{The `CONCAT` function is explained at https://www.excelfunctions.net/excel-concat-function.html}

Instead of using an `IsBlankRange` function, `CONCAT` could also be used directly in the `If` statement inside the `For` loop:

```
        If Trim(WorksheetFunction.Concat(Range(Cells(RowIndex, 3), Cells(RowIndex, LastColIndex))) & "") = "" Then
```

However, I believe that leaving the range evaluation in a separate function makes it easier to customise depending on the version of Excel being used, and it makes the `If` statement easier to read.

Comment: Thanks Noah for your reply and I agree on the loop to count down to 2. However, the line "If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(RowIndex, 3), Cells(RowIndex, LastColIndex))) = 0"  seems not working and no line get deleted. I set a breakpoint here, and found "RowIndex" and "LastColIndex" work well, but the Range(cells(...), (cells(...)) seems empty.  Thanks again.

Comment: I have double checked the code on another mocked spreadsheet, and it works well. For prior spreadsheet which didn't work, after I right click on the *empty* cells and clear the contents and it is working. But still not clear, why I need to "clear the content" where the cells are already empty. However, it is another topic, your method work perfectly, Thanks.

Comment: Hello, @user3684119, I appended some code to the answer to account for cells that may look empty but are not (probably because of spaces or some other peculiar character). This scenario meant using a more convoluted option than the more elegant `COUNTA` solution, but it is the only solution I can think of for now.

Comment: FYI, I appended some simpler code that makes use of Excel's new `CONCAT` function to account for cells that may look empty but are not. However, this simpler code will not work in versions of Excel that do not support `CONCAT`.

Comment: Awesome! Great to know, @user3684119!