# I keep getting an error within my code to autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the data in the cells underneath columns A and B if cell E is blank. I applied a filter to look at only the data with cell E empty however i am getting errors in my code. This is what i have

```
sht10.Range("E2").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="
```

I did already identify all my variables this is part of a larger code.

Comment: There is no `Field:=5` for a single column `Range`.  > `sht10.Range("E2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="`

Comment: This didn't work. It only displayed all empty rows not the ones with just cell E empty.

Comment: `sht10.Range("E2:E" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="` You can get the last row as shown [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920) Another example can be seen [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-condition/11317372#11317372)

Comment: Still didnt work. Only displaying completely empty rows. Need the ones with just cell E empty

Comment: Have you tried to incorporate the rest of your range > `sht10.Range("A2:E" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="`

Comment: I think I know why its not working. There is a formula in the cells I am looking for But not a displayed string

Comment: Filter is only applied on column `E`. It shouldn't matter whats in the other columns

Comment: it still is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Before:

[image]

Some code that "works":

```
Sub ytrewq()

    Dim sht10 As Worksheet
    Set sht10 = ActiveSheet

    sht10.Range("E2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="

End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

By "works" I do not mean it will do anything useful, only that it will SOMETHING without falling over dead.