# How to delete a row that has text in one column and a 0 in the next

Tags: excel, vba

This code works if i have two columns side by side both with zeros in them. But i need it to delete the row if the cell on the right has a value of 0. The cell on the left is a word if that makes a difference? Think of a shopping list with the items and their amounts needed in the column on the right

```
Sub DeleteRow()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = LastRow To 1 Step -1

        If Cells(r, 1) = 0 Then
            Rows(r).Delete
        End If

    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Cells(r, 2) = 0 Then` if you want to look at column B. Are you asking to add the logic to look at `cells(r, 1)` to see if it's text too?

Comment: [Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-condition) to looping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count of columns starts at 1 not 0 so the if statement should be:

```
If Cells(r, 2) = 0 Then
```

This is if your "right" column is column B, which it appears so from your initialization of LastRow.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to all this VBA stuff and spent way too much time trying to figure this out for myself haha. Thanks again!