# Excel VBA Command Button go to cell after complete find

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Im creating a excel booklist for our library and im using userform to insert new entry of books details. After user input the details into userform, I would like to check three items from (ISBNTextBox.Text, TitleTextBox.Text, CallNoTextBox.Text) if the book already exist in our list to avoid duplicate list. Then, if duplicate found, we can check the duplicate data by clicking the button and direct point to the cell of any three data above. Below some code that I already tried but not working. Can someone help me to fix it?

**UPDATE:
Tried one of those comment solution, its working but only for ISBN(Column E), for title and call number, when click only pointed to cell B1**

```
Private Sub Gotobutton_Click()

    Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
    Dim SearchString As Variant, FoundAt As String

    ''On Error GoTo Whoa

    Set ws = Worksheets("booklist")
    Set oRange = ws.Range("B:B, E:E, F:F")

    SearchString = Array(ISBNTextBox.Text, TitleTextBox.Text, CallNoTextBox.Text)

    Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell
        FoundAt = aCell.Address
        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                FoundAt = FoundAt & ", " & aCell.Address
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
    End If

    ''MsgBox "The Search String has been found these locations: " & FoundAt
    Application.GoTo Worksheets("booklist").Range(FoundAt)
    Exit Sub
''Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Let me know if you need xlsm file.

[image: Excel list sample]

Comment: You can only find one thing at a time.

Comment: Use [.Find and .FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: Alternatively, [Autofilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-condition/11317372#11317372) on all three fields

Comment: ^^^^ Better option.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing that, meaning need to find 1 by 1. Thats ok with me, can we find 1 by 1 from left to right using this list (ISBNTextBox.Text, TitleTextBox.Text, CallNoTextBox.Text)? Can some help?