# Deletes Headings when deleting rows with different criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue when deleting rows with certain conditions because it deletes my headers too, also ¿ is there a way to improving the deleting of rows with different criteria ?

```
Sub RO_FilterDelete()
Dim RowToTest As Long

For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row To 2 Step -1

With Cells(RowToTest, 1)
    If .Value <> "ONLINE" _
    Then _
    Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
End With

Next RowToTest

Dim RowToTest2 As Long

For RowToTest2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row To 2 Step -1

With Cells(RowToTest2, 6)
    If .Value <> "CONFIRMACIÓN DE INFORMACIÓN DE CONTRATO" _
    And .Value <> "ACTUALIZACIÓN DE INFORMACIÓN DE CONTRATO" _
    Then _
    Rows(RowToTest2).EntireRow.Delete
End With

Next RowToTest2
End Sub
```

The error comes from the macro that paste the data into the worksheet, it pastes it from A1 instead of A2, that's why the filter doesn't work.

```
Sub RechazosOnline()
Dim rsh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
Dim wbCopyFrom As Workbook, wsCopyFrom As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks("2. Detalle_Transacciones_pendientes_rechazadas_MDM_27Ene20.xlsx")
Set wbCopyFrom = Workbooks("1. ReporteGeneral_TransaccionesDiariasMDM_20200115")
Set wsCopyFrom = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets("Detalle")
wsCopyFrom.Range("A2:I" & wsCopyFrom.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).Copy

For Each rsh In wb.Sheets
         rsh.Range("A2:I" & rsh.Range("A" & rsh.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Use  union  method.  Search by union

Comment: In which row are your headers? BTW you don't need `RowToTest2`. You could just reuse the existing `RowToTest` in the second loop since its value doesn't need to be preserved for any other purpose. And, of course, you could combine the two loops by building a more elaborate AND/OR test.

Comment: Use Autofilter to delete as shown [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-condition) No need to loop.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, i'm gonna check it now, the header is in the first row so i don't know why is deleting it too, im gonna try the code from below.

Answer (score 0):

The both loop of your code are working for me.
As Variatus sugested, maybe your header aren't on the first row.

Have a nice day !

Comment: I think the error comes from when i paste the cells into the workbook, don't know for sure, gonna check it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the union method is convenient and fast.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngU As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim rngDB As Range

    Set rngDB = Range("a2", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For Each Rng In rngDB
        If Rng <> "ONLINE" Then
            If rngU Is Nothing Then
                Set rngU = Rng
            Else
                Set rngU = Union(Rng, rngU)
            End If
        End If
    Next Rng

    If Not rngU Is Nothing Then
        rngU.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    Set rngU = Nothing
    Set rngDB = Range("b2", Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For Each Rng In rngDB
        If Not (Rng.Value = "CONFIRMACION DE INFORMACION DE CONTRATO" Or Rng.Value = "ACTUALIZACION DE INFORMACION DE CONTRATO") Then
            If rngU Is Nothing Then
                Set rngU = Rng
            Else
                Set rngU = Union(Rng, rngU)
            End If
        End If
    Next Rng

    If Not rngU Is Nothing Then
        rngU.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```