# Filtering a value and then delete all values under that filter (Have own code, but doesn't seem to work)

Tags: excel, vba

I have received a code, however when I get to line 4, it doesn't actually filter out the value that I need it to. Everything else is working correctly. I have not included the Delete_Visible_Cells sub as I just need the filter to actually filter out the value I need.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
ActiveSheet.Range("L1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="6.1.1"
Call Delete_Visible_Cells
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet` is rarely a great place to start of from. Declare what sheet object you are working with first.

Comment: [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-partial-text/11317372#11317372) will set you on the right path on how to work with objects and apply the filter. And if I am not wrong, I think that question actually answers your query?