# VBA No Cells found error xlCellTypeBlanks

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Sub that goes through many worksheets and should delete any blank rows within the range. Sometimes it will work fine, but other times it gives me a "no cells found error" and fails. I don't understand why.

The error appears at the line `Set r = Range("B2:B" & counter).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`

I tried to catch this error by having an if statement to go to the test error handle but, by doing that the routine just doesn't delete anything as r is of course nothing then.

Is there perhaps an easier way to delete blank rows from multiple tabs, given that the blank rows can be in different positions each time the macro is run.

```
Sub RemoveBlanks()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim counter As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim cell As Range

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
        ws.Activate
        counter = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = Range("B2:B" & counter).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            If r Is Nothing Then
                GoTo test
            End If
        r.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
        
    End If
test: Next ws

Worksheets("Summary").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if you are aware that you can use [AUTOFILTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-partial-text/11317372#11317372) to achieve what you want. It is faster than looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` fails when there has never been any data in a cell. You are safer to do this way:

```
For i = counter To 2 Step -1
   If LenB(Cells(i, 2)) = 0 Then Cells(i, 2).Entirerow.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
Next
```

If you suspect having spaces in cells, you can apply

```
... LenB(Trim(Cells(i, 2)) ...
```

Comment: Very clean! What does LenB do? I've only ever seen Len.

Comment: `LenB` is slightly faster as it counts bytes while `Len` counts characters that takes extra effort in a Unicode environment

Answer (score 1):

Try it in this way, please:

```
'your code...
 On Error Resume Next
  Set r = Range("B2:B" & counter).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
 On Error GoTo 0
 If Not r Is Nothing Then  r.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
'your code...
```

Anyhow, this way is faster then iteration between each cell of the range

Comment: since it's in a loop, you must explicitely `set r = nothing` otherwise it might still have it's previous value

Comment: @Patrick Honorez: **Not at all**! First time when the range will include, at least, a blank cell it will return a correct (`r`) range.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no blank cells, you will get an error, you can resume next if there is an error.

```
    Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    
    For Each sh In Sheets
        On Error Resume Next
        If sh.Name <> "Summary" Then
            With sh
                .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```