# Filtering a column with AutoFilter

Tags: excel, vba

I want to filter a column with particular value.

Problem Statement:
Excel looks like below and the worksheet name is "Current_Data".
[image]

I need to filter the third column with value "VP" and get the output using Autofilter.

Code snippet:

```vb
Sub Filter_CP()
Sheets("Current_Data").Range("A1:D4000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="VP"
End Sub
```

I receive the below error:

> "Run-time error 1004: AutoFilter method of range class failed"

Instead of "Sheets", I tried with "Worksheets", without any luck.

Comment: Try something like `Sheets("Current_Data").Range("A1:D100").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="VP"`. I have hardcoded `100`. Replace it with the last row. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-partial-text) is an example

Comment: Thanks for the guidance Sidhharth, however it still yields the same error as before.

Comment: Post the updated code in your question

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: Is your worksheet protected?

Comment: Recording a macro of you doing it manually should give you code to check against what you have written.

Comment: even if i record a macro, while i m trying to run it , it is showing the same range class failed error

Comment: A long shot, but is the data starting in the 3rd row, and are the headers in the 1st and 2nd row merged cells? If so, unmerge them and rather increase the row size.

Answer (score 1):

Other users have suggested code that works, *assuming that your data is formatted correctly*.

Verify that:

- The left-most column of your range is A
- The right-most column of your range is D
- The first row of your range is 1

Once you have verified these things, try the code suggested by Siddharth Rout once again `Sheets("Current_Data").Range("A1:D4000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="VP"`

Furthermore, a screenshot that shows more could be useful to us when trying to help.  For example, we cannot see the column letters nor row numbers in your image.

Finally, I would have commented this if I had enough reputation to do so, so apologies for essentially proposing another user's suggestion as an answer.

Comment: I thought that 15 is needed for commenting?

Comment: @VBasic2008, it told me 50.